Why does this batch file minimize & not hide the console window in Windows 11 (PowerShell -WindowStyle Hidden)?
In Windows 11, the following batch file minimizes the console window:
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Minimize ;exit
notepad.exe

Why does the following batch file minimize, and not hide, the console window:
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden ;exit
notepad.exe


Appears the behavior is at least partially on purpose

@Ramhound Over 120 posts in that issue report!  At least on the surface, it looks like people have been struggling with this, or related issues, for over 7 years now.  I obviously haven't read that entire massive thread (yet?), but it sounds like the OP of that issue report is having an issue with the window flashing briefly.  I'm experiencing the window not being hidden at all; it's just minimized.

This code puports to fix it, but I have not implemented it (nor do I know how to turn it into an executable as yet).

@RonRosenfeld Thanks Ron.  If you click the following link, then click on Assets, you'll find an executable: https://github.com/SeidChr/RunHiddenConsole/releases

@AmazonDiesInDarkness Thanks. I need to better familiarize myself with GitHub's organization.

@RonRosenfeld You're welcome.  It's not always obvious.  Often the most important items are hidden one to three levels deep or inside a dropdown menu.  The UI and UX leave much room for improvement.

I tried the code with a task in task scheduler and, at least for the first trigger, it is working with no obvious issues.
